# WooCommerce REST API - 403 "This order is still being processed."

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-subscriptions

I try to get past orders (December) from WooCommerce. From 80.000 transaction I have about a 200 transactions that are not included in the /orders response, but show up in the Admin Dashboard. When I try to get such an order via the API directly (/orders/:orderId) I'll get `{ "error": "This order is still being processed." }`. The other 99% work flawlessly. I can't see a pattern and don't understand where this comes from. Any idea would be helpful.

The shop is also using woocommerce-subscritions, so it might be related to that (or not)

Comment: Do you use this plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-paypal-payments/. There are similar cases in the support section of this plugin.

Comment: AFAIK There is one similar case – opened by me yesterday. If you have seen other cases (probably with a solution or hint), please link them if possible.

Comment: do a search on 'This order is still being processed.' in your plugins and theme directory and let us know what file you find it in. It's not int he woocommerce plugin, so probably another plugin or in your theme.